# firebase - security rules REST

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm experimenting with `Firebase` and curious about the [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/).

Let's say you have a firebase data set represented as simply as:

```
{
 "myNewData" : "Some String"
}
```

How could you write a rule so that only an object that gets written has the key name `myNewData` ?

I'm using the `POST` method and the data is structured in Firebase as follows:

```
-myFireBaseapp
  -someData
       -RandomFirebaseKey
           -myNewData
       -RandomFirebaseKey
           -myNewData
```

in the simulator I came up with

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read":true,
        "$someData":{
       ".write":true,         
        ".validate": "newData.hasChild('myNewData')"
        }

    }
  }
```

which works in the simulator but not in postman.

`POST`

`http://myfirebase.app.bucket/someData.json`

```
   {
     "myNewData" : "Some String"
    }
```

Thanks for any info.

Comment: Show the minimal code that makes a REST call that fails.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen REST call falls in postman. Added post call above

Comment: That request is not sending any data, so will not satisfy the the security rules. Without a [minimal, complete example of what you're trying to do](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's hard to help. In this case for example, the two samples of you data structure vary on whether `myNewData` is a key of a value. I'll write up an answer that I hope is helpful.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen actually the data I'm trying to send is above. It's just the key/value "myNewData" : "Some String"

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen when I remove the rules the request from postman works but of course , not ideal for my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your data to always have a key `/someData/<anyKey>/myNewData` with any value, you can validate that with

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read":true,
      "someData":{
          "$anyKey": {
              ".write":true,         
              ".validate": "newData.hasChild('myNewData')"
          }
       }
   }
 }
```

If you squint your eyes, you can still see the path in these rules `/someData/$anyKey/myNewData`.

If you also want to validate that the value of `myNewData` is a string, you'd expand the rules to:

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read":true,
      "someData":{
          "$anyKey": {
              ".write":true,         
              ".validate": "newData.hasChild('myNewData')",
              "myNewData": {
                  ".validate": "data.isString()"
              },
              "$other": {
                  ".validate": false
              }
          }
       }
   }
 }
```

I also added a `"$other: { ".validate": false }` to that last sample, which ensures that writes with any non-specified keys are rejects. So now the `/someData/$anyKey` can *only* contain a `myNewData` property that is a string.

This is all covered in the Firebase documentation on [Using $ Variables to Capture Path Segments](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#using_variables_to_capture_path_segments), which I highly recommend studying.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot for the example. Going to give this a shot in a few hours and report back to you.

Comment: I surfed through their documentation briefly but didn't catch variables capability. Thanks